M2M authentication but one side is public
I've looked at Auth0 and firebase, but both these options always either require you to store a client secret on both machines or active user interaction.
Basically the thing I had in mind is just the simple: a key is given to the public machine at startup, it is sent to the private machine, private machine checks the key and sends a value/secret back to the public machine,which it can use to start working.
It is very easy to extract hardcoded values out of the public machine, which is why I can't really trust it with a client secret to do the typical client credentials grant thing.
Bonus points if there's a free service or tier out there for this.
Edit: To clarify I am developing a plugin for an application, but parts of the plugin are confidential and are loaded in remotely to prevent malicious users from simply reverse engineering the confidential parts. (I realize it's not completely waterproof but it's going to be very tedious at the very least)
My plugin will be started programaticaly and receive arguments containing a key, which will then be used to load in the confidential functionality. So 99% of the time there won't be a user there to click through some online login page either. In general it's just not a viable option here.
The problem is thus I can't trust this plugin with a client secret to make a traditional credential grant type authentication. I am looking for a way to authenticate without having to embed secrets into the plugin.

This cannot be answered in its current form. What is the question? What do you actually want to achieve? Is there a user involved at any point, or pure machine to machine? What exactly do you mean by public? What do you mean by "giving it a key at startup"? And so on, please provide a lot more detail, or better, a more concrete example, otherwise this cannot be answered.

Updated the post, hope this clarifies things

Yes that helps. You will probably not like this but this cannot be done in any way that is actually secure, you can't authenticate software in this sense. There are some other answers (from me and others too) detailing why. If this was possible, software piracy would not be a thing, but it very much is. You can perhaps make it harder for an attacker, but in this case even doing that to a reasonable extent sounds hard.

I see, kinda feared that'd be the case. Though are there any techniques to make it extra tedious?
